# Puppeteer file-chooser upload not working

Tags: file-upload, puppeteer, filechooser

I try to upload a video on instagram using puppeteer with FileChooser:

```
const selectBtn = await page.$x("selector...")

const [fileChooser] = await Promise.all([
  page.waitForFileChooser(),
  selectBtn[0].click()
]);

await fileChooser.accept(["./myvid.mp4"]);
```

But it is not working, nothing happens.
Did anyone get that to work or an idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Following the [document](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.waitforfilechooser), it should be:

```js
const [fileChooser] = await Promise.all([
  page.waitForFileChooser(),
  page.click('selector...'),
]);
```

Comment: does it work for you?

Comment: Of course it's working for me

Comment: with instagram? what do you have as your selector?

Comment: Which Instagram version do you use? Web mobile or desktop? Mobile version is always easier for Puppeteer than Desktop version.